# In backbone.js When I using unset() by passing { validate: true } can force validate?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I using unset() by passing { validate: true } can force validation?

```
var Person = new Backbone.Model({ name: 'byer' });

Person.validate = function(attrs) {

  if (!attrs.name) {

    return 'I need your name';
  }

};

Person.set({ name: 'byer' });
console.dir(Person.attributes);

Person.unset('name');
console.dir(Person.attributes);

Person.unset('name', { validate: true });
console.dir(Person.attributes);

Person.unset('name', { validate: false });
console.dir(Person.attributes);
```

What's difference between by passing { validate: ture } and { validate: false }?

If I don't passing anything options, validation will be false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I don't passing anything options, validation will be false?

Yes. By default Backbone won't perform validation.

Below is the code for `unset`:

```
unset: function(attr, options) {
  return this.set(attr, void 0, _.extend({}, options, {unset: true}));
},
```

So its just `set` with an extra flag `unset`. Now the code that performs set/unset based on this `unset` flag is after the code that performs the validation. If validate flag is passed (`{ validate: true }`) and the validation fails, the action won't be performed else the action will be performed.

Passing `{ validate: false }` and not passing validate flag has the same effect - the action will be performed without any validation.